# Show three ways that $f(z)=\frac{\overline{z}}{z-1}$ is not analytic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, parametric

I need to show the complex function $$f(z)=\frac{\overline{z}}{z-1}$$ is not analytic in three ways; using Cauchy's equations, geometrically, and by integrating over the circle of radius 2.

I used Cauchy's equations using $u(x,y)=\frac{x^2-x-y^2}{(x-1)^2+y}$ and $v(x,y)=\frac{y-2xy}{(x-1)^2+y}$.The calculations were complicated, but I managed to show they were not equal.

For the second part, I chose the lines $x=1$ and $y=1$, mapped them, and showed that the slopes of their tangents at their intersection points did not meet at a right angle. I believe this answers the question.

My biggest question lies in the integral. I did it, but got 0. Here is what I did:
We want $$\oint_C \frac{\overline{z}}{z-1}$$, where $C$ is given by $|z|=2$. I chose to parameterize $z$, giving $z=2e^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq2\pi$. This gives $\overline{z}=2e^{-it}$ and $dz=2ie^{it}dt$, and so I integrated the following: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2e^{-it}}{2e^{it}-1}2ie^{it}dt.$$ Unfortunately, upon integration, I got that the integral is equal to $0$. I didn't expect this, as the integral should vanish if it is analytic, but it clearly is not at $z=1$. Did I make a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you let $\bar{z} = 1/z$?

Comment: Maybe $\bar{z}=4/z$, since you are integrating on $|z|=2$. The function $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ has two poles, in $z=0$ and $z=1$, so if you integrate on the previous circle the residue theorem gives zero. Try to change the radius of this circle into $\frac{1}{2}$: in such a way we have one singularity and one non-zero residue.

Comment: Fourth way: if $f$ is analytic, then $(z-1)f = \bar{z}$ is analytic. But it isn't! And according to WolframAlpha, the integral is $0$. You could show that the integral is $0$ along a circle of radius $2$, but diverges along a circle of radius $1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Careful, the function in question does not have two poles. While it is true that along the circle in question that $\bar z = 4/z$, it is not true that this is the case for the function $f(z)$ in its domain. This function has no pole at the origin.

Comment: @SimonRose: yes, you are right, but the integral of $f(z)$ along $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ is the same as the integral of the meromorphic function $\frac{C}{z(z-1)}$ that *has* a pole in the origin. I was meaning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you made a mistake at all; in fact, what you found is in line with what you should expect.

When you are asked to show that $f(z)$ is not analytic, they mean other than at $z = 1$, where it is clearly not analytic since it his a pole. However, if it were analytic other than at $z = 1$, you would be able to use the residue theorem (since there is a pole inside the circle) to conclude that
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz = 2\pi i Res_{z=1}f(z) = 2\pi i
$$
However, you found that the integral was zero. So the function is not analytic (away from the pole).

Comment: How do you compute the "residue" at $z=1$? Since the function is not analytic, the usual formulas break down.

Comment: Well, you can assume by contradiction that the function analytic, which case the coefficient of $1/(z-1)$ in the series expansion about that point would be the residue. Since $\bar z$ is not singular at that point, you can just evaluate it at $z = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the difficulty of the Cauchy-Riemann equation approach: if $f(z)$ were analytic anywhere except at the point $z=1$, then $(z-1)f(z)$ would also be analytic. But $(z-1)f(z)=\bar{z}$ is not analytic anywhere, since $\frac{\partial{\bar{z}}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{\bar{z}}}{\partial{y}}=1+i(-i)=2\neq 0$.

In general, if $f(z)=\bar{z}g(z)$, where $g(z)\neq 0$ is analytic, then $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\bar{z}\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}+g(z)$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\bar{z}\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}}-ig(z)$. It follows that, $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\bar{z}\left (\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}}\right )+2g(z)=2g(z)\neq 0$. Therefore, the Cauchy-Riemann equation is not satisfied and the function is not analytic anywhere in the complex plane.